# Training for TED (aka Impossible dip)

Tags: strength, bodyweight-exercises, calisthenics, conditioning

What would you recommend to start training the ted? (aka the impossible dip)

I know that the main focus of this exercise is on the triceps and the elbow, so for the moment I'm doing bodyweight dips, muscle-ups (mainly to strengthen the elbows) and some triceps extension.

Since this exercise is mainly done by conditioning and strength, what is the best exercises/methodology to train it?

Comment: I have never trained for the TED, but I would imagine weighted dips and negatives would help.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQYRipdsBrY?

Comment: @SeanDuggan thanks fot the great video!